# When using CMake and g++, the compiler output does not have any coloring or formatting

Tags: fedora, make, cmake, g++

I'm using Fedora 38 (KDE, wayland), g++ 13.1.1, CMake 3.26.4, and GNU Make 4.4.
My problem is as follows:
When running `g++` directly, the output (e.g. errors, warnings, ...) is nicely formatted, using bold face and colours:
[image: Output with just g++]
However, when configuring the compilation with CMake, and then running `make`, the output is not formatted:
[image: Output with Make]

Here's the code I've used:
main.cpp:

```
int main(){
    compilation_error;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.4)
project("show-colour")

add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

How can I get the nice output formatting back?

When searching for a solution, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73724467). However, its solution doesn't appear to apply in my case: I've tried both with and without

```
set(ENV{CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS} ON)
```

which didn't make a difference, and `CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE` is `ON`.

Comment: You say you're running `make`, but the output identifies itself as `gmake` - do you perhaps have `make` aliased to something (like `gmake GCC_COLORS=` for example)? In the absence of a cmake-generated Makefile, what happens if you type `make main` in the directory that contains `main.cpp`?

Comment: What happens if you pass `-DCMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS=ON` to CMake flags?

Comment: Sorry, this question is no longer relevant. I installed a new OS, as that Fedora 38 system was super unstable (black screen shortly after login both on Wayland and X11, and overall a lot of weirdness).